# hyperbolic isometry

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, geometric-group-theory, isometry

I have a project I have to do. In order to do it I need to investigate this [book](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/groupeshyperboliques-english.pdf).

In page 94 they defined hyperbolic isometry on a metric s.t it possesses no fixed point in the tree.

After that they claim that such isomtery possesses 2 fixed point in the boundary of a tree.

How could it be ?
How it possesses no fixed point in the tree but 2 fixed point in the boundary of a tree ?
Is it a typo ?

were they meant to elliptic isometry ?
I having a little difficult to understand the proof

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no typo, a hyperbolic isometry on a tree fixes two points at infinity. For instance, you may think about the unit translation on the real line: it has no fixed point on the real line itself, but it fixes the two points at infinity.

Some hints to prove that a hyperbolic isometry $g$ on a tree $T$ fixes exactly two points at infinity:

- Let $x \in T$ satisfying $d(x,gx)= \inf \{ d(y,gy) \mid y \in T \}$, and let $\gamma_0$ be a geodesic from $x$ to $gx$. Prove that $[g]=\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} g^n \cdot \gamma_0$ defines a bi-infinite geodesic on which $g$ acts by translation.
- Deduce that $g$ fixes at least two points at infinity.
- Let $\xi \in \partial T$ be a point at infinity, and let $\gamma$ be geodesic ray from $x$ to $\xi$. Then $g \cdot \xi$ is the point at infinity associated to the infinite ray $g \cdot \gamma$. Prove that $g \cdot \xi \neq \xi$ if $\gamma$ is not included into $[g]$.
- Conclude that the only points of $\partial T$ fixed by $g$ are the two endpoints of $[g]$.

Comment: Thx!! but I would be glad if you tell me what is the unit translation on the real line. is it [0,1] -> R ?

Comment: The unit translation on the real line is just $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x+1$.